# 2016 13' MBP - No password accepted after a failed update. How could I possibly recover or get this data back?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, partition, password

FYI, I was at onetime a ACMT. So feel free to talk fast. I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016) that appears to have failed an update due to not having enough space. (I'll never understand why the installer can't check for free space before attempting to upgrade but whatever. That's another issue.)

I have the macbook connected via Target Disk mode over thunderbolt. I have 3 partitions. `Macintosh HD` `Macintosh HD - Data` and `Update`.

`Macintosh HD` and `Update` Are mountable. However `Macintosh HD - Data` is not (Probabaly locked by file vault). When prompted for the password. No password works for any user. Even the password for the localadmin account that uses a known shared password.

What leads me to believe it's a Space issue is because, On the `Update` partition, there is a file called `Restore.log` (https://pastebin.com/7d0qifX0)

That contains the following lines around Line: 1157.

> 04358000 : [-[UMEventRecorder _recordEvent:information:callback:]]
> (prepareFinished) - {
> failureReason = "MSU 1048 (ParallelPatchExtractPayload() 'main' returned -1660120036);";
> purgeableSpace = 0;
> result = "MSU 1048"; }   04358000 : ERROR - unable to write event to file: 'Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=640 "You can’t save the
> file
> “2DCD8733-0E6B-421C-85E1-D99D386F0E15-prepareFinished-1613671503449-0.plist”
> because the volume “Update” is out of space."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Volumes/Update/db/UpdateMetrics/Events/2DCD8733-0E6B-421C-85E1-D99D386F0E15-prepareFinished-1613671503449-0.plist,
> NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbc1be08670 {Error
> Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device"}}'

How can I get the data from the Data partition. or recover from this scenario without wiping the drive. Of course the user doesn't have a TM backup.

Comment: Follow instructions here.  https://mrmacintosh.com/big-sur-upgrade-not-enough-hd-space-serious-issue-possible-data-loss/

Comment: Note from the above link, TD mode with filevault needs a High Sierra or earlier Mac to unlock it.

Comment: Reading now. Thank you both. Will update in a few.

Comment: @MarcWilson I ended up installing Mojave from a USB installer to a External drive. Then booted to the external drive using Option. I was able to mount the DATA partition and copy all the user data. 
As a test, I used disk utility to erase the MacHD partition and now I can boot via TDM and connect it to the Big Sur Mac and mount the drive as expected (Password works). Thanks again Marc for that article. and THANK YOU MR. MACINTOSH!

Comment: Mr. Macintosh's site is down Today. So Strange. I have linked to his latest update video about the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8d939VAPU8